# How to adjust feed length to match image height on Zebra iMZ320 Printer

Tags: android, image, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I am using Zebra iMZ320 Printer. I am trying to print a PNG image through the Zebra Utilities app from an android device. Is there any way to adjust the length of the feed to match the image height without the image stretching? Currently, the only command I sent to the printer using the Zebra Setup Utility is:

`! U1 "ezpl.media_type" "continuous"
 ! U1 "ezpl.print_mode" "tear off"`

Answer (score 0):

There is full example (Objective-C) of printing UIImage, by using ZEBRA iMZ320. I think, you can use the same print commands  and prepare appropriate code in Java or Kotlin:

```
    UIImage *image = ...; //printing image; default wight should be ~572
    id<ZebraPrinterConnection, NSObject> connection = [[MfiBtPrinterConnection alloc] initWithSerialNumber:serialNumber];
    if (![connection open]) {
        NSLog(@"Printer Error! Please check the printer and try it again.");
        return;
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    id<ZebraPrinter, NSObject> printer = [ZebraPrinterFactory getInstance:connection error:&error];
    PrinterStatus *status = [printer getCurrentStatus:&error];
    if (status == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    } else if (!status.isReadyToPrint) {
        NSLog(@"The printor is not ready to print");
        return;
    }
    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    //Send configuration command with setting "media_type" = "continuous" and "printing height" = "imageSize.height"
    for (NSString *cmd in @[@"! U1 setvar \"ezpl.media_type\" \"continuous\"\r\n",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"! U1 setvar \"zpl.label_length\" \"%d\"\r\n", (int)imageSize.height]]) {
        if (![[printer getToolsUtil] sendCommand:cmd error:&error]) {
            NSLog(error == nil ? @"Printer Error! Please check the printer and try it again." : [error localizedDescription]));
            return;
        }
    }
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    if ([[printer getGraphicsUtil] printImage:[image CGImage] atX:0 atY:0 withWidth:-1 withHeight:-1 andIsInsideFormat:false error:&error]) {
        status = [printer getCurrentStatus:&error];
        int i = 0;
        while (!status.isReadyToPrint || i > 30) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
            status = [printer getCurrentStatus:&error];
            i++;
        }
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        NSLog(@"Prining should be success");
    } else {
        NSLog(error == nil ? @"Printer Error! Please check the printer and try it again." : [error localizedDescription]));
    }
    for (NSString *cmd in @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"! U1 setvar \"zpl.label_length\" \"%d\"\r\n", 50],
                            @"PRINT\r\n"]) {
        [[printer getToolsUtil] sendCommand:cmd error:nil];
    }
    [connection close];
```